# Readers-writers problem with writer priority

Tags: concurrency, semaphore

## Problem

In the book "Little Book of Semaphores", p. 71, there is the following problem:

> Write a solution to the readers-writers problem that gives priority to writers. That is, once a writer arrives, no readers should be allowed to enter until all writers have left the system.

I arrived at a solution, but it's a bit different from the one given in the book.

## My solution

**Shared variables**:

```
readSwitch = Lightswitch()
writeSwitch = Lightswitch()
noWriters = Semaphore(1)
noReaders = Semaphore(1)
```

`Semaphore(1)` means a semaphore initialized to 1, and `Lightswitch` is defined in the book like this:

```
class Lightswitch:
  def __init__(self):
    self.counter = 0
    self.mutex = Semaphore(1)

  def lock(self, semaphore):
    self.mutex.wait()
    self.counter += 1
    if self.counter == 1:
      semaphore.wait()
    self.mutex.signal()

  def unlock(self, semaphore):
    self.mutex.wait()
    self.counter -= 1
    if self.counter == 0:
      semaphore.signal()
    self.mutex.signal()
```

**Reader logic**:

```
noReaders.wait()
noReaders.signal()

readSwitch.lock(noWriters)

# critical section for readers

readSwitch.unlock(noWriters)
```

**Writer logic**:

```
writeSwitch.lock(noReaders)
noWriters.wait()

# critical section for writers

writeSwitch.unlock(noReaders)
noWriters.signal()
```

## Book's solution

**Shared variables**:

```
readSwitch = Lightswitch()
writeSwitch = Lightswitch()
noWriters = Semaphore(1)
noReaders = Semaphore(1)
```

**Reader logic**:

```
noReaders.wait()
readSwitch.lock(noWriters)
noReaders.signal()

# critical section for readers

readSwitch.unlock(noWriters)
```

**Writer logic**:

```
writeSwitch.lock(noReaders)
noWriters.wait()

# critical section for writers

noWriters.signal()
writeSwitch.unlock(noReaders)
```

## Questions

1) In the reader logic, in my solution, `noReaders.signal()` immediately follows `noReaders.wait()`. The idea here is that `noReaders` behaves as a kind of turnstile that allows the readers to pass through it, but is locked by a writer as soon as one arrives.

However, in the book's solution, `noReaders.signal()` is done after calling `readSwitch.lock(noWriters)`.

Is there any reason why my ordering would produce an incorrect behavior?

2) In the writer logic, in my solution, `writeSwitch.unlock(noReaders)` comes before `noWriters.signal()`. However, the book places them in the reverse order. Is there any reason why my ordering would produce an incorrect behavior?

## Edit: additional question

I have an additional question. There is something that I am probably misunderstanding about the book's solution. Let's say that the following happens:

- Reader 1 acquires `noReaders` (`noReaders` becomes 0)
- Reader 2 waits in `noReaders` (`noReaders` becomes -1)
- Writer 1 waits in `noReaders` (`noReaders` becomes -2)
- Reader 3 waits in `noReaders` (`noReaders` becomes -3)
- Reader 4 waits in `noReaders` (`noReaders` becomes -4)
- Reader 1 acquires `noWriters` (`noWriters` becomes 0)
- Reader 1 signals `noReaders` (`noReaders` becomes -3; Reader 2 gets unblocked)
- Reader 2 passes through `noWriters` lightswitch; signals `noReaders` (`noReaders` becomes -2, 
  Reader 3 gets unblocked)

In the above situation, it seems that additional readers can keep arriving and entering the critical section although a writer is waiting.

Besides, considering that reader and writer are looping, a reader that finished the critical section could loop around and wait on `noReaders` again, even if there are writers already waiting.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your solution, the following situation is possible:

- A new writer comes after `writeSwitch.unlock(noReaders)` but before `noWriters.signal()`
- New writer executes `writeSwitch.lock(noReaders)`
- A reader executes `readSwitch.lock(noWriters)`, going into critical section even if there is a writer.

The book's solution wakes up waiting writers first before waking up the readers. Your solution wakes up readers first, and also allows readers to queue up at `readSwitch.lock(noWriters)` so they can run even if there is a writer waiting.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that, in the writer, the order of the last two lines in my solution should be reversed: the writer should signal `noWriters` before it unlocks `noReaders`, so that it gives priority to waiting writers. However, it's still not clear to me why the first two lines of my solution's reader are in the wrong order. I also added an "Edit: additional question" section with additional doubts. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: For the new addition to your question: note that readers are in critical section without `noReaders` lock. So, as soon as a reader goes into its critical section, a writer can execute a lock on `noReaders`, preventing other readers. True, by the time that happens other readers can go in, but reader the spec: once a writer arrives, all writers must be processed. It doesn't say as soon as a writer arrives it must be admitted.

Comment: Your reader solution, with its lock/unlock, allows readers to queue up at `readSwitch.lock(noWriters)`. So when a writer completes and releases `noWriters`, readers may go in even if there is a new writer.

Comment: It seems a lot clearer now. After the reader acquires `noReaders`, it must lock `noWriters` _before_ signaling `noReaders`. Otherwise, a reader may be able execute `readSwitch.lock(noWriters)` and go into the critical section as soon as a writer signals `noWriters`, even if there are other writers waiting.